# Import Error: No module name

Tags: python-3.x

I am facing some issue while importing a class.
The folder structure is as below:

```
python_space
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ ds_Tut
     |_ __init__.py
     |_ stacks
        |_ __init__.py
        |_ stacks.py  (contains class Stack)
     |_ trees
        |_ __init__.py
        |_ parseTree.py (wants to import Stack class from above)
```

Used the following code to import:

```
from stacks.stacks import Stack
```

Getting the following error:

```
"ImportError: No module named stacks.stacks"
```

Comment: Where you used `from stacks.stacks import Stack`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Referencing another project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476111/python-referencing-another-project)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sibling package imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stacks is inside the ds_Tut module. does this work?

```
from ds_Tut.stacks.stacks import Stack
```

Comment: ok, then what is the result of `import sys; print(sys.path)`?

Comment: the premise when creating packages is that the root directory of your package (`python_space`) is in your path. you should ensure that every executable adds this path in some way or other to the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: `['/home/piklu/python_space/ds_Tut/trees', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`         This is the output of print(sys.path)

Comment: `/home/piklu/python_space/ds_Tut/trees` is the first entry: it should be `/home/piklu/python_space`. you need to set this either in python using `sys.path` or in the environment (your shell) in `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: importing successfully now. Added: 
`import sys` 
`sys.path.insert(0, '/home/piklu/python_space')`  inside parseTree.py

Comment: personally, inside a package i assume that the path is set correcly. i keep the executable scripts somewhere outside the package - they are responsible that the `PYTHONPATH` is set correctly.